# Add Decimal to data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a value in one of my column as 'P62519' I am trying to add decimal after first three digit for this column as 'P62.519' but its not working, the data type for this column is nvarchar(10)

```
Update Table
Set ColumnName =   REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Table.ColumnName,1,3)),'','.')
where LEN(Code) > 3
```

I tried this  but this Column Columnname is clustered primary key with another column in my table and would not let me do it saying violating constraints, although I am not sure if the above I am doing is correct. Can please someone suggest how I can add decimal after three places in these values in my database? Thanks for your help

Comment: If the column is part of a primary key you'll need to drop the constraint before updating the values and then re-add them afterwards but this is risky as you may corrupt the data

Comment: Make sure you back up the table, that update statement doesn't look correct

Comment: Yes this is just a test table, But can someone correct what I am doing wrong in update statement please? I know its probably incorrect, Can someone suggest please, How Can I add decimal after first 3 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your foreign keys have specified the referential triggered action `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

I think the `UPDATE` should look more like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET ColumnName = SUBSTRING ( ColumnName, 1, 3 ) + '.' 
                       + SUBSTRING ( ColumnName, 4, LEN ( ColumnName ) - 3 )
 WHERE LEN ( ColumnName ) > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is acting as a primary key, you shouldnt, your environment is correctly telling you that your primary key will break if the change is made!

Could you not just add the decimal in your application layer instead?

Comment: I got it working using below :). Thanks all
Update Table Set Columnname= SUBSTRING(Columnname,1,3)+ '.'+ SUBSTRING(Columnname,4,4)
where LEN(Columnname) > 3

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function:

```
UPDATE atable
SET Code = STUFF(Code, 4, 0, '.')
WHERE LEN(Code) > 3
```

Also be sure to pay attention to [@onedaywhen's advice about updating foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885564/297408).